# C#. Что стоит изучать: WinForms, WPF, или UWP?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, uwp

Начал изучать C#, спустя некоторое время захотелось перейти с консоли на нечто более глобальное и графонистое. Спустя часы поиска в гугле понял что выбор стоит между WinForms, WPF и UWP. Как я понял WinForms нужны сейчас для приложений где не важен дизайн, а нужна простота интерфейса и большая производительность. Ну а что с wpf и uwp? Что из этого выбрать? Гуглил уже много раз, но так и не понял, чем же они существенно отличаются кроме того что uwp только под win 10. И что будет лучше изучать в 2020?

Comment: Все просто, UWP - Windows 10, WPF - все. Сейчас Microsoft анонсировали `Project Reunion`, который объединяет это все под одно общее крыло, а также `WinUI 3`, но это опять же, все под Windows 10 на сколько я понял. Так что, если хотите нового, то UWP и далее - ваше, если же хотите простой .exe файл, который можете запустить например на win7, то WPF.

Comment: Классическое Windows приложение это WinForms.

Comment: В любом случае нужно изучать не платформу(WinForms/WPF/UWP) а шаблон(паттерн) программирования, а актуальный на данный момент это MVVM, который нужно использовать в WPF/UWP и можно в WinForms.

Comment: `WinForms нужны сейчас для приложений где не важен дизайн` "Где не важен дизайн" можно и WPF/UWP использовать, не вижу разницы.

Comment: WPF и UWP похожи, сможете в одно, другое тоже получится. WinForms хорошо для понимания, как винда работает. Но красивые штуки в WinForms творить сложнее, чем в WPF или UWP. Я рекомендую попробовать WinForms и WPF, а UWP само приложится при необходимости. И согласен с оратором выше про MVVM. **WPF+MVVM** - мой выбор. Но не забудьте про изучение ООП и всякие принципы SOLID.

Comment: в 2020 году не так много пишут настольных приложений. Но если вам оно надо, и вы планируете windows-only приложение, то WPF будет лучшим вариантом.

Comment: В реальной работе равно вероятно как то, что вам ничего из перечисленного не понадобится (web-проекты, unity), так и то, что вам понадобится это все и еще чуть-чуть, т.к. старые проекты и их код до сих пор работают и требуют поддержки, а иногда и активного развития. Так что имеет смысл ознакомиться со всем перечисленным, разобраться в основных подходах и принципах, и углубиться в то, что больше понравится. Недостающее всегда можно добрать из документации или исходников.

Comment: Знания WPF помогут при работе с AvaloniaUI, про которую почему-то не упоминали, но которая разрабатывается уже 8 лет и вполне уже Production-Ready.

Comment: Ещё на подходе MAUI

Comment: WPF и UWP отличаются ещё и тем, что UWP - это приложения для Windows Store, которые работаю в песочнице и им нужно задавать разные разрешения в манифесте. Там чуть урезанные биндинги, но зато есть компилируемые биндинг x:Bind, которые тоже не для всего подойдут. Есть очень крутые анимации 60 FPS, которые считаются не в UI потоке и много чего ещё. По WPF есть хорошие книги, начни с него, на UWP будет легко переключиться. В UWP ещё больше заточено всё на одно окно и постраничную навигацию. В WPF можешь делать обычное приложение с кучей окон и т.д., а можешь навигацию прикрутить со страницами.

Comment: По WinUI есть книга "Изучаем WinUI 3.0". 
----------
WinUI - это шаг MSFT в направлении унифицированной платформы разработки Windows. Попытка объединить UWP, WPF и другие фрэймворки для разработки пользовательского интерфейса.
----------
WinUI - является набором элементов управления и библиотек с открытым исходным кодом, которые предназначены для использования в приложениях для Universal Windows Platform (UWP).

Comment: У UWP приложений есть жизненный цикл. Он чем-то похож на жизненный цикл мобильных приложений. Распространение через Microsoft Store. Прохождение ревью перед релизом. Ограничения способов оплаты, которые, возможно, сейчас сняты (я не в курсе), но какие гарантии на будущее? Оно тебе нужно сейчас всё это? Начни с WPF, потом можно или в MAUI или AvaloniaUI, в зависимости от задач.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows Forms.**

Плюсы:

- WYSIWYG дизайнер форм
- Компонентная архитектура
- Поддержка невизуальных компонентов
- Поддержка детерминированного уничтожения
- Полная интеграция с базовыми библиотеками .NET
- Нативные элементы управления идеально вписываются в тему Windows, потому что являются её частью
- Экономное потребление системных ресурсов
- При грамотном использовании компонентной модели рутинная работа может быть сведена к нулю, и программу с большим количеством однотипных форм можно написать за день.

Минусы:

- Привязка данных только к свойствам и только по смене фокуса
- При масштабировании экрана в новых Windows может съехать раскладка, это старая технология, которая на это не рассчитана. Правда, при наличии парка тестовых машин всё отлаживается.
- В основе технологии лежат нативные элементы управления Windows, их внешний вид сложно изменить, и типовое приложение выглядит скромно (обычно для преодоления этих недостатков используются специальные сторонние библиотеки наподобие Infragistics или DevExpress)
- Есть вероятность потери большого количества работы при ошибке в дизайнере. Как правило, ошибки возникают при работе со сторонними компонентами.

**WPF.**

Плюсы:

- При ошибке в работе дизайнера ничего фатального произойти не может, потому что внешний вид приложения описывается как xaml
- Возможность настроить внешний вид стандартных элементов управления практически как угодно, плюс разработать свои нестандартные элементы управления
- Проблемы при масштабировании экрана в новых Windows возникают гораздо реже, чем при использовании Windows Forms
- Привязка данных гибко настраивается
- Поддержка анимации, звука, 3D графики

Минусы:

- Писать xaml гораздо дольше, чем пользоваться дизайнером Windows Forms. Кроме того, декларативный код и большей концентрации требует при написании, и отлаживать его практически невозможно. Ну и в целом архитектура технологии не располагает к быстрой разработке, сложнее автоматизировать рутину.
- Непредсказуемое поведение при изменении темы Windows. Теоретически, WPF подстраивается под тему Windows, но на практике её элементы управления выглядят по-разному в зависимости от темы Windows, но всё равно не нативно. Будет точнее сказать, что она пытается это делать, но делает плохо.
- Плохая интеграция с базовыми библиотеками .NET Framework. Такое ощущение, что WPF писали в целом далёкие от основного стека .NET люди
- Как следствие, отсутствует поддержка невизуальных компонентов и детерминированного уничтожения. Компонентная модель не то чтобы совсем не поддерживается, но как-то уж очень выборочно.
- Стандартные элементы управления содержат ряд странных недоработок (например, полосы прокрутки без возможности задать минимальный размер ползунка, а так же их некрасивое расположение в таблицах данных).
- Неудобная система задания расположения элементов управления через явные номера строк и столбцов в самом распространённом контейнере. При изменении во внешнем виде приложения нужно их исправлять во всех элементах управления.
- Постоянно что-нибудь масштабируется, даже если явно просишь это не делать, и в результате размывается - шрифты, растровые картинки. Причём ещё и не всегда, это зависит от монитора, видеокарты и темы Windows.
- Использование рекомендуемого Microsoft паттерна MVVM приводит к раздуванию объёма исполняемого кода.
- Отсутствует диалог выбора директории из коробки
- Отсутствует поддержка MDI из коробки. Поскольку это базовая функция практически в любом приложении, приходится либо делать самостоятельно, либо искать сторонние решения
- Высокое потребление системных ресурсов
- Иногда начинает глючить сам графический движок и рисовать хаос из пикселей вместо того, что запрограммировано

**UWP** я не использовал, знаю понаслышке. Не знаю, исправили ли в нём косяки WPF, но это точно похожая технология.

Плюсы:

- Интеграция с магазинами приложений
- Возможность разрабатывать приложение параллельно под разные платформы (Windows, Android)
- Добавили встроенную поддержку диалогов

Минусы:

- (?) В основе технологии лежит WPF, наверняка с большинством выше указанных косяков
- Отсутствует возможность подключения к базе данных
- Работает только на новых Windows (вроде бы начиная с 10)

Что касается производительности, то по моим впечатлениям, WPF быстрее работает на новых машинах, а Windows Forms на старых. При этом на старых машинах Windows Forms не тормозит вообще (но тормозить могут другие части приложения, например, база данных), а в остальных случаях некоторые фризы и подвисания всегда присутствуют. В .NET Core Windows Forms урезанная и глючная, WPF не знаю, не пробовал.

Таким образом, основные потребности в разработке базовых приложений лучше закрывает Windows Forms. Если нужно, чтобы приложение просто красиво выглядело, но функциональность была более-менее стандартная (кнопки, меню, поля ввода), следует использовать сторонние компоненты под Windows Forms. WPF имеет смысл использовать для каких-нибудь специфических задач, требующих именно нестандартной векторной графики и не требующих хорошей совместимости программы с разными машинами. UWP имеет смысл использовать для разработки тонких клиентов популярных сервисов под разные платформы.

Comment: "Использование рекомендуемого Microsoft паттерна MVVM приводит к раздуванию объёма исполняемого кода."
Так в Windows Forms используется MVP паттерн или не используется. Так же в WPF - можно писать не используя этот паттерн ровно как в Windows Forms.